# How do I get flowchart to query SQL table/view

Tags: powerbi, diagram, visio, flowchart

I have a SQL Oracle database with material transfers that I want to connect to this flowchart. I have the flowchart in Visio, but I also have access to power BI. Preferably this flowchart would fetch numbers live or upon an easy refresh, I don't want to have to import a table each time. And hopefully later I want to have the option to select a time period, for example between May and June 2023, and it will get the sum of materials transferred through each of the nodes and display it in the flowchart.
what is the easiest way to achieve this? I'm not sure where to ask so sorry if this is not the correct place.

[image: Flowchart in question]

Not sure where to look or how to start.